# how to filter a model objects by related table's foreign key in django REST

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to make an API for a restaurant, and my `models.py` is like this:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    is_free = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.id, self.name, self.is_free)


class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    table_id = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_price = models.IntegerField()
    factor_id = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.order_id, self.table_id.id, self.total_price)


class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    order_detail_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food_id = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.order_detail_id, self.order_id, self.food_id.name)
```

When an Order with a Table created, some OrderDetails should add to it.

I want to filter all OrderDetail objects that are for a specific Table and are for the latest Order(I mean all OrderDetail objects that are active now). The client request URL with filter contains `table_id` and not `order_id`. How can I filter OrderDetail objects by the table that have it?

> Each table can only have one order in a moment, When an Order creates with a specific Table, the `is_free` will set to False. So the `table_id` field of Order class should be `models.ForeignKey` not `models.OneToOneField`, I think so! :) If it's wrong please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
order_detail_queryset = OrderDetail.objects.filter(
    order_id__table_id=table_id,
    order_id=Order.objects.filter(
        table_id=table_id).latest(
        'table_id'))
```

I didn't tested the answer, but it might work as expected

Comment: Thank you @Jerin , I change 'id' to 'table_id' and now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your model is that *Table* never gets new entries and you generate new *Order* based on the *Table* that has *is_free* set to **TRUE**.

So, in order to get the *Order* from *table_id* you require some field by which you can get the latest order of that *Table*.
Right now you have *order_id* but I would not suggest you to do it. The best way could be to add some Date/Time field in class *Order*.

Your query could be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderDetail WHERE order_id = (SELECT order_id FROM Order WHERE table_id = <table_id> ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Hope that helps.